# Unable to change the password for normal user : getting message "Sorry"

Tags: hp-ux, password-reset

I'm trying to change the password for one of the user names called "test1". When I tried it didn't asked me to update the new password it just errored saying "Sorry".

```
$ passwd
Changing password for test1
Old password:
Sorry.
```

Answer (score 0):

Means that you didn't enter old password correctly.